# PHP & MYSQL Is this MySQL Syntax correct for UPDATE/INSERT IF EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

My plan is to update/insert existing/new records into a database from an external, i have the information set to go into the database, but cannot check if it exists already.

my first attempted at doing database stuff

```
    $link = resdb::connect();
    $q = "IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM property AS this WHERE this.name = $propertyname ) )"
         ."begin"
            // UPDATE PROPERTY IF IT EXISTS
            ."UPDATE property (name, propertylocation, propertyrating, propertytype)" 
            ."SET ($propertyname, $locationid, $ratingid, $typeid)"          
            ."WHERE name = $propertyname"
         ."end"
         ."ELSE"
         ."begin"
            ."INSERT INTO property (name, propertylocation, propertyrating, propertytype)" 
            ."VALUES ($propertyname, $locationid, $ratingid, $typeid)"
         ."end";
    $r = mysqli_query($link, $q);
    if($r > 0){
        return true;
    }
```

A unique id is made on completion of each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a unique index on the name column:

```
ALTER TABLE property ADD UNIQUE KEY(name)
```

Now you can use the MySql `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`

```
INSERT property (name, propertylocation, propertyrating, propertytype)
VALUES ($propertyname, $locationid, $ratingid, $typeid)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    propertylocation = VALUES(propertylocation),
    propertyrating = VALUES(propertyrating),
    propertytype = VALUES(propertytype)
```

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Don't forget to sanitize database inputs.

Comment: great easier than TSQL method. upvote and answered. thank you